# AFNetworking file upload works with my php script but doesn't work with jsp script

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I'm writing an iPhone app which sends some information (some text and an image) to a server script.

with my php script all works well, but with my customer's jsp script (which sends an email with the received info to an email address) nothing works... (I know cause I should receive the autoreply email and this doesn't happen).

I haven't access to my customer's script cause they are a big customer and "some bla bla security issues..." 
the script works properly with the online web form and it worked well with ASIHTTPRequest on iOS 4.3 (I'm migrating to AFNetworking cause with iOS 5 ASIHTTPRequest doesn't work)

any help is really appreciated!!!

here is my code... note that my code always reaches NSLog(@"Success") but I don't receive any auto reply email, so it's not working!!

```
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.client.server.com"]];


    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setObject:[fieldName text] forKey:@"field01_nome"];
    [parameters setObject:[fieldSurname text] forKey:@"field02_cognome"];



    NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/Contents/mail/sendToForm.jsp" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:myNSDataToSend mimeType:@"image/jpeg" name:@"alleagto"];
    }];


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFHTTPRequestOperation HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:myRequest success:^(id object) {
        NSLog(@"Success");

    } failure:^(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Fail");

    }];


    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

    }];

    queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
```

Thank You very much!!

EDIT: As suggested by JosephH I've added the captured requests:

Request generated from the Online Web Form (which works always):

```
POST /Contents/mail/sendToForm.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: my.client.server.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22
Content-Length: 54246
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  */<- added by me for syntax coloring
Origin: http://www.client.server.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Referer: http://www.client.server.com/form/1/send-the-form.shtml
Accept-Language: it-it
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive

------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_recipient"

4182fd0f318e1d86176a3be7f8c7d83955eb5eca2e1402250e47164caf1984e7
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_subject"


------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field01_nome"

Gianluca
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field02_cognome"

Pisati
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field03_indirizzo"

A
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field04_provincia"

B
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field05_email"

my_email@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field06_telefono"

333
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field07_tipo"

valore2
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="allegato"; filename="allegato.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Here there's the attachment

------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field09_oggetto"

Test Web
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field10_segnalazione"

Send Test Web
------WebKitFormBoundaryLWVo7zrkX3QOybWm--
```

Request generated from the iOS 5.0 with ASIHTTP (I don't know why, but sometimes it works, other times no...)

```
POST /Contents/mail/sendToForm.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: my.client.server.com
User-Agent: My App 1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iPhone OS 5.0; en_US)
Content-Length: 153522
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: close

--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field01_nome"

Gianluca
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field02_cognome"

Pisati
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field03_indirizzo"

A
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field04_provincia"

B
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field05_email"

gianluca.pisati@gmail.com
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field06_telefono"

333
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field07_tipo"

valore2
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field09_oggetto"

Test iOS 5
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field10_segnalazione"

ASIHTTP on iOS 5
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_recipient"

4182fd0f318e1d86176a3be7f8c7d83955eb5eca2e1402250e47164caf1984e7
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_subject"


--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="allegato"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Here there's the attachment

--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY-ABC90FA4-3EE3-42FE-B93A-A698D7BB894D--
```

Request generated from iOS 5.0 with AFNetworking (which never works):

```
POST /Contents/mail/sendToForm.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: my.client.server.com
User-Agent: com.mycompany.myapp/1.0 (unknown, iPhone OS 5.0, iPhone Simulator, Scale/1.000000)
Content-Length: 153203
Accept: */*                     */<- added by me for syntax coloring
Accept-Language: en, fr, de, ja, nl, it, es, pt, pt-PT, da, fi, nb, sv, ko, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ru, pl, tr, uk, ar, hr, cs, el, he, ro, sk, th, id, ms, en-GB, ca, hu, vi, en-us;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Connection: keep-alive


--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_recipient"

4182fd0f318e1d86176a3be7f8c7d83955eb5eca2e1402250e47164caf1984e7
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field04_provincia"

B
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field05_email"

gianluca.pisati@gmail.com
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field07_tipo"

valore2
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field01_nome"

Gianluca
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field10_segnalazione"

AFNetworking on iOS 5
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field02_cognome"

Pisati
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_subject"


--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field06_telefono"

333
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field09_oggetto"

Test iOS 5
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field03_indirizzo"

A
--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="allegato"; filename="allegato-342447627.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Here there's the attachment

--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY--
```

Answer (score 0):

ASIHTTPRequest works just fine on iOS 5.0; 100s of apps that use ASIHTTPRequest have zero problems on iOS 5.

That said, moving to AFNetworking probably makes sense in the long term.

These "it works in the browser but not with " type problems are difficult to solve by code inspection - the easiest way to solve them is to install a tool like charlesproxy.

Once installed, start it capturing, then perform the request in the browser, verify it was successful, then perform it from the iOS simulator. Then compare the request from the browser against the one from AFNetworking, and see what differences you can spot.

If you can't figure it out, edit your question to include the two captured requests and I'm sure someone will be able to spot it.

Comment: thanks for the advice..!! The only thing that changes is the order of the parameters, could this be the problem? I don't think so...

Comment: Are you sure that's the only thing that's different - did you compare all the headers? If that is the only thing that is different, it surely must be the problem - I am sure there will be other differences though.

Comment: ok, I've added 3 captured request, the first one is from the Web form, the second one is with ASIHTTP (sometimes with iOS 5 it doesn't work! I don't know why...), the third one is with AFNetworking

Comment: You could try making some of the headers more consistent - eg. Accept:, User-Agent:, Origin:, Referer:, Accept-Language and a few others are all different between the two requests. Also, do you check if the server is sending you anything back? Sometimes there can be an error message in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a problem with AFNetworking and multipart/form-data. Solved. When AFNetworking generates HTTP body for multipart/form-data it puts \r\n sumbols at the beginig. Difference between your AFNetworking body and other bodies - is \r\n at the begining. Try to remove it. I've modified some AFHTTPClient.m methods to remove them from body's begin :

```
static inline NSString * AFMultipartFormEncapsulationBoundary() {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@--%@%@", @""/*kAFMultipartFormLineDelimiter*/, kAFMultipartFormBoundary, kAFMultipartFormLineDelimiter];
```

}

and:

```
- (void)appendPartWithHeaders:(NSDictionary *)headers body:(NSData *)body {
    [self appendString:AFMultipartFormEncapsulationBoundary()];

    for (NSString *field in [headers allKeys]) {
        [self appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@%@", field, [headers valueForKey:field], kAFMultipartFormLineDelimiter]];
    }

    [self appendString:kAFMultipartFormLineDelimiter];
    [self appendData:body];
    [self appendString:kAFMultipartFormLineDelimiter];
```

}

It works for me